# How to import open source library as an external project into Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, zxing

I want to change some thing in this open source library: https://github.com/zxing/zxing , my question is how to add this library as an external project in my project in Android Studio such as we were doing previous in Eclipse to can change any thing I want in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File-->New-->import Module.

File -->Project Structure-->click on '+' Left Corner-->Module Dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow these steps

1.Compress library into .zip file

2.Rename .zip into .jar

3.Put jar in project's lib file

4.In Android Studio, navigate to the .jar file, right-click and click "Add As Library..."

Answer (score 0):

If they provide gradle denpendenies, you can just import in in `build.gradles`

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/aaa.jar')
    compile 'bbb@jar'
    compile 'ccc'
}
```